# How to limit the number of products displayed in cart list in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to adjust the number of products displayed in cart popup list in prestashop. If I bought too much products. The popup menu will be very long. I already disable the pics. Like below:
[image] [image: Add a new product without refresh]

And if I add a new product, its pic is still there. After I refresh the page the pic is gone.

All I have done is to disable the code in blockcart.tpl

```
    {*<a class="cart-images" href="{$link->getProductLink($product.id_product, $product.link_rewrite, $product.category)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"><img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'cart_default')}" alt="{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" /></a>*}
```

So I have 2 problems:

How to limit the number of products displayed in cart list in prestashop?

How to solve the bug in the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the image problem:

Open your /themes/%your_theme%/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js file, and look for `displayNewProducts` function. You will need to comment the line that displays the image, just look for `img` tag and you'll find it.
It displays the image because on page load the cart block is rendered via PHP/Smarty, however, when the contents change or any other action on cart block is detected, the list refreshes via javascript. Which is why initially you don't see a picture, but then it shows up when you add a product.

As for the limit - I am not sure, is this legal to hide ordered products? I mean, I know that when you navigate to the actual cart you'll see them, but it's illegal in some countries (including mine) to hide the ordered items from the customer. Maybe consider making the product list scrollable  - this way the products will still be there, but they won't take up too much space.

Comment: Thanks. OMG. It may be illegal . I decide to makie the product list scrollable. Any hint, bro?

Comment: I had good results with [slimScroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll), but this is not really required, you can achieve this with pure CSS as well, something like dl.products {max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;} should work just fine. Adjust `max-height` to your liking, if the list is taller than 100px, a vertical scroll bar will be displayed. If you want a nicely styled scroll bar, however, go with slimScroll, or any other solution - you'll be able to style the scroll bar however you want.

Comment: Yes, I solved my problems. And about the slimScroll. I set the height as 250px. It fixed as 250px even if my content is not as much as 250px. XD. I am looking for a  solution.

Answer (score 0):

Option one jump into code and change the "limit" in the query 
option two do some css by limiting the max height of the cart product container div and scroll if overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use some jQuery to limit the amount items visually in the cart.

The picture problem is because you are using PHP, it won't be constantly running, only on page load so that's why you need to refresh to remove the image, change to JS/jQuery with this as well and it will remove the image once the cap is reached automatically without needing to reload.